# How to add Health Probe id TO LB Rule while creating using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to add a LB Rule using Terraform but unable to find a way to refer existing probe id ( Health Probe).
Below is my code.

```
resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb-rules" {
  resource_group_name            = var.lb_rg
  loadbalancer_id                = data.azurerm_lb.lb.id
  name                           = var.LB_Rule_Name
  protocol                       = var.protocol
  frontend_port                  = var.frontend_port
  backend_port                   = var.backend_port
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = var.frontend_ip_configuration_name
  backend_address_pool_ids = [data.azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend.id]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [azurerm provider docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_rule):

> The following arguments are supported:
>
> ...
>
> probe_id - (Optional) A reference to a Probe used by this Load Balancing Rule.

Therefore:

```
resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb-rules" {
    [...]
    probe_id = azurerm_lb_probe.your_probe.id
}
```

Comment: @kam bajn - Thanks for your comment but my question is how can i get existing probe information (because there is no data source for probe ) from LB so i can use in LB Rule Creation.

Comment: For an existing probe you can: 1) import it into Terraform; 2) retrieve its id outside of Terraform (via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/load-balancer/load-balancer-probes/list)?); 3) if you know an existing rule name that uses the probe you, use azure_rm_rule data source to get it via `data.azure_rm_rule.some_rule.probe_id`.